# Display a message when the cursor is ON the button (and disable the click)

Tags: javascript, html, django

## JavaScript

```
    $(function(){
        $('.select-another-button').each(function(){
          $(this).bind('click', function(e){
            $('#message').show()
            setTimeout(function(){ $('#message').hide() }, 300000);
            e.preventDefault();
            fileBrowser(this);
            return false;
          });
        });
      });
```

## HTML

```
 <a href="#"
        title="{% trans "Send email - rejected file(s)" %}"
        class="btn btn-icon select-another-button"
        data-url="{% url "messaging:send" request_id=object.pk %}">
        <i class="material-icons">assignment_late</i>
         <div class='alert alert-success' id='message'>
            The message was sent to the client. Please wait 5 minutes before sending the message again.
         </div>
    </a>
```

## Django

```
app_name = 'messaging'
urlpatterns = [
    ...

    url(r'^send/(?P<request_id>[0-9]+)/$',
        send, name='send'),
]
```

and

```
@staff_member_required
@csrf_exempt
def send(request, request_id=None):
    req= Request.objects.get(pk=request_id)
    request_folders = req.folder.all_files.all()
    context = []

    for doc in request_folders:
        if doc.meta.state == u'rejected':
            context.append(doc)

    if context:
        ctx = {'request': req}
        EmailFromTemplate('document-refusal', extra_context=ctx)\
            .send_to(req.customer.user)

    return HttpResponse('')
```

The purpose of this code is to create a button which will send a email under specific conditions. My weakness is probably with the HTML and the jS part. Once a user click the button, I want a delay of five minutes before he could send the message again. Hence, I have to desactivate the button for five minute once it is use and display the message : '*The message was sent to the client. Please wait 5 minutes before sending the message again.*' when the cursor is **ON** the button. How could I modify the JS part so that it can do what I want?

---

## Update

```
      <div class="title-actions">
        {% if not object.is_readonly %}
        {# TODO: apply perms #}
        <a href="#"
          id="id_select_request_document"
          title="{% trans "Select file(s)" %}"
          class="btn btn-icon select-button"
          data-turbolinks="false"
          data-save-label="{% trans "Ok" %}"
          data-close-label="{% trans "Cancel" %}"
          data-copy-to="{{ folder.pk }}"
          data-reload="true"
          data-url="{% url "documents:ajax-select" folder_id=object.customer.folder.pk %}">
          <i class="material-icons">folder</i>
        </a>
        {# TODO: apply perms #}
        {# if permissions.has_add_children_permission and not folder.is_root #}
        <a href="#"
          id="id_upload_request_document"
          title="{% trans "Upload file(s)" %}"
          class="btn btn-icon upload-button"
          data-turbolinks="false"
          data-url="{% url "documents:ajax-upload" folder_id=folder.pk %}"
          data-complete-post="{% url "requests:validate-requirements" pk=object.pk %}"
          data-max-uploader-connections="1">
          <i class="material-icons">cloud_upload</i>
        </a>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="overlay"></div>
            <a href="#"
               title="{% trans "Send email - rejected file(s)" %}"
               class="btn btn-icon select-another-button"
               data-url="{% url "messaging:send" request_id=object.pk %}">
                <i class="material-icons">assignment_late</i>
                <div class='alert alert-success' id='send-message' style="display: none;">
                    <p>
                    The message was sent to the client. Please wait 5 minutes <br> before sending the message again.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
        <a href="{{ folder.get_admin_directory_listing_url_path }}" class="btn-icon"><i class="material-icons">settings</i></a>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
```

Before modifications, I got [right display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJJ3e.png), but now I have [wrong display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvP5j.png).

I don't know if it is good, but I put the following block at the top of my `.html` file.

```
<script type="text/css">

    .wrapper{
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #overlay{
      display: none;
      position: absolute;       
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      opacity: .1;
      background-color: blue;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

## CSS

```
.title-actions {
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 13px; }
  .title-actions a {
    transition: background 0.3s ease; }
    .title-actions a.btn {
      padding: 2px 14px;
      line-height: 26px;
      max-height: 28px;
      position: relative;
      top: -1px;
      margin-left: 8px; }
    .title-actions a:hover {
      background: #4382b5; }
  .title-actions span {
    color: #444;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 6px; }
  .title-actions .btn {
    padding: 2px 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    max-height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    margin-left: 8px; }
  .title-actions .btn-icon {
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    color: #3e5366;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 !important;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    margin-top: -16px;
    margin-left: 6px; }
    .title-actions .btn-icon i {
      font-size: 35px;
      line-height: 20px;
      position: relative;
      top: 12px; }
    .title-actions .btn-icon:hover {
      color: #4382b5;
      background: transparent; }
  .title-actions .badge .material-icons {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 4px; }
```

Comment: So, what the problem you are facing ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa First, I just don't know how to deactivate the button. Secondly, I don't even know how to display my message when the cursor is on the button and has already been clicked. Honnestly, I don't know I can be more precise than that. I don't know enough tools so far to do such thing.

Comment: So after disabling, everytime the user hovers on the button you want the message to pop?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Yes, this is right. An example or reuse the same code would be very appreciate. It's been a while I am on this problem.

Comment: Ok, and I assume you have multiple `.select-another-button` on that page?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Yes, but the purpose of those are different. I mean I have also `.select-button` so I use `select-another-button` for that specific button

Comment: Hope you have only 1 element with `id` as `message`. `id` has to be unique for a page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a lot of changes to your code. Assuming you have only 1 element with an `id="message"`.

Starting from your JQuery code.

```
$(function(){
  $('.select-another-button').each(function(){
    $(this).bind('click', function(e) {
      $(this).attr('disabled','true'); //disables the button
      $('#overlay').show(); //after disabling show the overlay for hover
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        $(this).attr('disabled','false'); //enables after 5mins
        $('#overlay').hide(); //hide the overlay
      }, 300000);
      e.preventDefault();
      fileBrowser(this);
      return false;
    });
  });
});

$("#overlay").hover(function(){
    $('#message').show();
},function(){
    $('#message').hide();
});
```

Since a **disabled button cannot have `hover` events on it**, you need to put a transparent overlay over the button & show the `#message` on its hover.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <a href="#"
     title="{% trans "Send email - rejected file(s)" %}"
     class="btn btn-icon select-another-button"
     data-url="{% url "messaging:send" request_id=object.pk %}">
    <i class="material-icons">assignment_late</i>
    <div class='alert alert-success' id='message' style="display: none;">
    The message was sent to the client. Please wait 5 minutes before sending the message again.
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

And ofcourse the CSS change to make sure the `overlay` is placed properly over the button which will be later disabled.

```
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
#overlay{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;       
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: .1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('.select-another-button').each(function(){
    $(this).bind('click', function(e) {
      $(this).attr('disabled','true');
      $('#overlay').show();
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        $(this).attr('disabled','false');
        $('#overlay').hide();
      }, 300000);
      e.preventDefault();
      fileBrowser(this);
      return false;
    });
  });
});

$("#overlay").hover(function(){
    $('#message').show();
},function(){
    $('#message').hide();
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
#overlay{
   display: none;
    position: absolute;       
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: .1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="overlay"></div> 
  <a href="#"
     title="{% trans "Send email - rejected file(s)" %}"
     class="btn btn-icon select-another-button"
     data-url="{% url "messaging:send" request_id=object.pk %}">
    <i class="material-icons">assignment_late</i>
    <div class='alert alert-success' id='message' style="display: none;">
    The message was sent to the client. Please wait 5 minutes before sending the message again.
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I got I little issue. Could you just help me with that? I'll modify my question in such a way you could understand better.

Comment: Ok, I will try.

Comment: Did you forget me?

Comment: @J.Doe - I see, this is a CSS issue. there seems to be few styles already applied to `<a>` inside `class="title-actions"`. Now that we have added a `div.wrapper` outside the last icon, its causing this. Can you show all the CSS relating to the icons(`<a>` inside `.title-actions`).

Comment: I've modified my question. You'll be able to see it at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to fix it now?